# How to display custom layout multiple times in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Custom Rating bar layout in Xamarin, I want to display it multiple times in my form but it is displaying only once even though i have declared it multiple times but is showing only one time & last layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="Reviews"
             xmlns:customcontrol="clr-namespace:MyApp.NestedLayouts"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Reviews">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="4.5" FontSize="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                <customcontrol:RattingBar x:Name="layout1" ImageWidth="20" ImageHeight="20" RequiredStarValue="5"
                                          SelectedStarValue="5" FillStarImage="StarF.png" EmptyStarImage="star.png" />
                <Label Text="2 Reviews"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Row 0 -->
                <customcontrol:RattingBar ImageWidth="18" ImageHeight="18" RequiredStarValue="5" x:Name="layout2"
                                          SelectedStarValue="5" FillStarImage="StarF.png" EmptyStarImage="star.png" />
                <BoxView Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource gray}"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                <!-- Row 1 -->
                <customcontrol:RattingBar ImageWidth="18" ImageHeight="18" RequiredStarValue="4" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="layout3"
                                          SelectedStarValue="4" FillStarImage="StarF.png" EmptyStarImage="star.png" />
                <BoxView Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="1"
                         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource gray}"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="1"/>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the layout Which i want to use multiple times but can't achieve (I have added my Views in backend).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.NestedLayouts.RattingBar">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ContentView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use content view instead of content page to reuse this view inside multiple pages.

Comment: View tag can't have any child.

Comment: One directly. Embed your code for example in stacklayout or grid. To be sure I am referencing to ContentView. I made edit to my answer.

Comment: I have removed ContentView & Made stack layout as a one parent No other layout in it. but still same.

Comment: Sorry for confusion I mean ContentView instead of ContentPage.

Comment: If i make it as a ContentView instead of ContentPage, Xamarin doesn't consider it as a page & now it's not allowing me to move to this page like Navigation.PushAsync(new Reviews()); Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyApp.Pages.Reviews' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Page'

Comment: You can create new ContentPage programmatically, add your ContentView to it, then navigate to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code of your `RattingBar`, but you can refer to this sample [here](https://github.com/Xamarians/RatingBarSample).

class CustomRatingBar

```
   class CustomRatingBar:View
    {
        public event EventHandler<float> RatingChanged;
        public event EventHandler Tapped;

        public static BindableProperty IsSmallStyleProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsSmallStyle", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomRatingBar), false);
        public bool IsSmallStyle
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSmallStyleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsSmallStyleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static BindableProperty IsReadonlyProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsReadonly", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomRatingBar), true);
        public bool IsReadonly
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadonlyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsReadonlyProperty, value); }
        }

        public static BindableProperty MaxStarsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MaxStars", typeof(int), typeof(CustomRatingBar), 5);
        public int MaxStars
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxStarsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxStarsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static BindableProperty RatingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Rating", typeof(float), typeof(CustomRatingBar), 0f);
        public float Rating
        {
            get { return (float)GetValue(RatingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RatingProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged("Rating"); }
        }

        public static BindableProperty StepSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("StepSize", typeof(float), typeof(CustomRatingBar), 0.5f);
        public float StepSize
        {
            get { return (float)GetValue(StepSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StepSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public void OnRatingChanged(float rating)
        {
            if (RatingChanged != null)
                RatingChanged.Invoke(this, rating);
        }

        public Color GetFillColor()
        {
            return Rating == 0 ? Color.Gray : Rating <= 2 ? Colors.StarRed : Rating <= 3 ? Colors.StarOrange : Rating <= 4 ? Colors.StarYellow : Colors.StarGreen;
        }

        public void OnTapped()
        {
            if (Tapped != null)
                Tapped.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" >
            <uc:CustomRatingBar x:Name="customRatingBar" MaxStars="5"  RatingChanged="OnRatingChanged"
                                IsReadonly="false"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Text="Give Rating" TextColor="Green" FontSize="Medium"  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

           <uc:CustomRatingBar x:Name="customRatingBar2" MaxStars="5"  RatingChanged="OnRatingChanged2"
                                IsReadonly="false"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
```

The result：
[image]

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Shoukat  Have you resolved your question?